# Best practice to manage xml data source in nodejs environment

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, mongodb, web-services

Im developing a web application using node/express and the "data source" of the application are some xml files. Basically I buy this data from an external company that periodically update the data and I can get them via webservice. While this scenario is very similar to a normal xml web service, I need to store these xml files in local before process them because of restriction to access the webservice.
Also, considering I need to do some sort of queries on these data, I was thinking to load the xml files in mongodb but Im not sure this is the best way considering that the source files are updateted every 3-4 seconds.
And I also dont know how to load in a proper way these files in mongodb, thanks

Comment: How big are these file? Are there a lot of them? Is update incremental or simply overwriting?

Comment: the files are always less then 1megabyte each and the one that require frequent update are actually 102kilobyte. They are in total 30 files more or less. update is overwriting